# How can show ages according specific years?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to show ages according a specific rank of ages.

Here is the [demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e0fe4/3):

```
CREATE TABLE clients
(date_birth date, date_anniversary date);

INSERT INTO clients
(date_birth, date_anniversary)
VALUES
('1991-01-04',NULL ),
('1992-01-05',NULL ),
('1993-01-06',NULL ),
('1994-01-07',NULL ),
('1995-01-08',NULL ),
('1996-01-09',NULL ),
('1997-01-10',NULL ),
('1998-01-11',NULL ),
('1999-08-12',NULL ) ;
```

Here is the query,it shows all ages converted.

```
SET @start:='0'; 
SET @end:='22';

SELECT YEAR(CURDATE())- year(date_birth) AS ages
FROM clients
```

I'm trying to show ages between 0 AND 22, I tried this [demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e0fe4/6) :

```
SET @start:='0'; 
SET @end:='22';

SELECT YEAR(CURDATE())- year(date_birth) AS ages
FROM clients
WHERE year(date_birth) >= @start AND year(date_birth) <= @end
```

Please somebody can help me or advice me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: your `where` is pointless. it's the equivalent of `1995 >= 0 AND 1995 <= 22`. You're directly comparing **YEARS** against **AGES**. Why not just `WHERE YEAR(birthday) >= (YEAR(CURDATE()) - 22)`? and note that this isn't accurate, especially for people whose birthday comes later in the year (e.g. they're still 21)

Comment: Sorry I got it now SET @ start:='0'; 
SET @ end:='22';

SELECT YEAR(CURDATE())- year(date_birth) AS ages
FROM clients
WHERE  YEAR(CURDATE())- year(date_birth) >= @ start AND  YEAR(CURDATE())- year(date_birth) <= @ end

Comment: You can also use having clause [*`demo`*](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e0fe4/19)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your query should be

```
SELECT YEAR(CURDATE())- year(date_birth) AS ages
FROM clients
WHERE date_birth <= (curdate() - interval @start year) 
and date_birth >= (curdate() - interval @end year)
```

This will make use of your index on date_birth as well (if any).

Comment: Wait a second I tried with other dates and is not working http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d62017/4

Comment: Your sample gives me the results. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d62017/4/2 What is not working?

Comment: Should be between 0 AND 22 and this only show 0 and 21

Comment: I don't think so. Please note that '1992-01-06' is beyond 22 years. Note that the month is January resulting in 22 years and 7 months (and hence falling beyond 22 years). If you want a more precise example, use '1992-09-06'. Hence, the answer that you have marked as the answer to your question is actually incorrect.

Comment: Didn't notice will check it.

Answer (score 2):

Change your query to be this:

```
SET @start:='0'; 
SET @end:='22';

SELECT YEAR(CURDATE())- year(date_birth) AS ages
FROM clients
WHERE YEAR(CURDATE())- year(date_birth) >= @start 
  AND YEAR(CURDATE())- year(date_birth) <= @end
```

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to use the variables in the query that way you don't have to reset them

```
SELECT YEAR(CURDATE())- year(date_birth) AS ages
FROM clients
CROSS JOIN(SELECT @start := 0, @end := 22)t
HAVING ages BETWEEN @start AND @end
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e0fe4/31)